# How to connect multiple tabled database with flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and need to complete a project with at least two tables in a database. I have already written code useful for a single table in the database. Now I need help to incorporate another table to the code as well but I don't know how.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
  cur.execute("SELECT * FROM student")
  data = cur.fetchall()
  cur.close()
  return render_template('index.html', student=data)


@app.route('/insert', methods=['POST'])
def insert():
  if request.method == "POST":
    flash("Inserted Successfully!")
    name = request.form['name']
    email = request.form['email']
    phone = request.form['phone']

    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO student (name,email,phone) values 
         (%s,%s,%s)", (name, email, phone))
    mysql.connection.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

I need help to perform the same tasks as above but with a different table in the same database.

Comment: in your post request give the parameter plus database name , in function method according to the database write the query and it will cone

Answer (score 0):

Awful answer but it works, just do the same thing pointing to another table:

```
@app.route('/table2')
def table2():
  cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
  cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table2")
  data = cur.fetchall()
  cur.close()
  return render_template('table2_visualize.html', data=data)


@app.route('/insert_into_table_2', methods=['POST'])
def insert_into_table_2():
    if request.method == "POST":
        flash("Inserted Successfully!")
        #Params for table2 here, e.g.
        param1_table2 = request.form['param1']

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO table_2 (param1) values 
        (%s)", (param1_table2))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('table2'))
```

Now when you post onto server:port/insert_into_table_2 it will get inserted onto your table2 (which you have to define on your sql DB)

And when you go to server:port/table2 you will render a template(which you also have to create) called  table2_visualize.html with a variable called data.

You REALLY want to not use SQL directly, that is what is called sql injection, but I supose for homework it might be fine.

Further reading, check MVC and ORM

Comment: not a good method, it works still not a good one, better to  add the database as param and on same link hit this post to get the data and according to the database param do the processing

Comment: ````Now I need help to incorporate another table to the code as well but I don't know how````` Don't think this is asking for best practices, he just wants to understand how flask works and how to add a second table, a quick and easy prototype is sometimes better to understand things.

Comment: it's not best practice, but it works,i mentioned  it , better if taken database as param also and then proceed on that basic,

Comment: Yes, but that is NOT the question